# How to use which.max in R accounting for groups to impute missing values?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the following dataframe (where both are factor variables):

```
     A   B
1 pine NA
2  fig 234
3  fig 234
4  fig 145
5 pine 123
6  fig NA
```

I'm wanting to replace missing values in B with the most frequently occurring value within  group A in the dataset. The above would become:

```
     A   B
1 pine 123
2  fig 234
3  fig 234
4  fig 145
5 pine 123
6  fig 234
```

I've found the code below on a similar question which makes use of the which.max function, but can't seem to get it work group wise, with it returning the overall max of column B for every NA value, instead of the max within each group of A.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  add_count(B) %>%
  mutate(B = if_else(is.na(B), B[which.max(n)], B)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Do I need an extra group by somewhere?

Comment: If both of them are factor, either create a new level in that column before `replace`ment or convert to `character` class

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode).  After grouping by 'A', use the `na.aggregate` from `zoo` specifying the `FUN` as `Mode` to replace the NA elements with the `Mode` of that column

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
      group_by(A) %>%
      mutate(B = na.aggregate(B, FUN = Mode))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   A [2]
#  A         B
#  <chr> <int>
#1 pine    123
#2 fig     234
#3 fig     234
#4 fig     145
#5 pine    123
#6 fig     234
```

where

```
Mode <- Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("pine", "fig", "fig", "fig", "pine", "fig"
), B = c(NA, 234L, 234L, 145L, 123L, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see that works with the test data but not with my actual dataset, so there's something going on with my data that I don't realise. I also tried converting columns to character and numeric types but no luck.

Comment: @Hulleo I showed an example with `dput` to make it reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You can try(Maybe not the most elegant):

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("fig", 
"pine"), class = "factor"), B = c(NA, 234L, 234L, 145L, 123L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))

#Code
df %>% left_join(df %>% filter(!is.na(B)) %>% group_by(A,B) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(A) %>% filter(N==max(N)) %>% rename(Fill=B)) %>% group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(B=if_else(is.na(B),Fill,B)) %>% select(-c(Fill,N))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   A [2]
  A         B
  <fct> <int>
1 pine    123
2 fig     234
3 fig     234
4 fig     145
5 pine    123
6 fig     234
```